# How can I eject a Time Machine drive quickly?

Tags: time-machine, external-disk

I have a Time Machine drive for my laptop...

[image]

I bring the machine to work. Every morning I right-click "Eject" the drive, and it takes forever or just doesn't eject.

I'm in a hurry, so I either `sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now` or if I'm really in a rush just yank the drive (then get scolded by the OS when I log back in later).

What would be a better way?

---

MacBook Pro mid 2012 ; OS 10.12.1 (Sierra)

Comment: Does `diskutil unmount "/Volumes/NameOfDisk"` work?

Comment: Time Machine must not be running when you want to eject the drive.

Comment: set up timer for time machine to stop before you wake up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd party app named [Mountain](http://appgineers.de/mountain/) that gives you control over all your connected volumes. It's not free, selling for $7 but they have a free trial period so you can test drive it. Mountain creates a menu item that user can use to mount, unmount, eject or load volumes. I can't guarantee it is faster than your method but I use it to mount or unmount stubborn drives.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too much data to backup. reduce your time machine backup to an interval smaller than 4 hours, if the unmount is slow it is because the backup has too much to backup, or that your antivirus slows it a lot. therefore, if there is less to backup before ejection the unmounting should be quicker. Do not also forget to check monthly if your disk transfert rate become too slow, (copy a big file and count the time) . very long disk access are a sign for a forthcoming disk failure...

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/02/change-the-time-machine-backup-schedule/

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear problem with backups for laptops. You want portability, and don't want to wait hours for a backup to finish.

Firstly, killing the backup processes while running may result in corrupted backup files: yanking the drive out may damage the mechanical drive itself causing loss of the whole volume.

How much data are you creating each day? Once the first backup on your entire storage is created, then it should only be adding the delta (changed files) every hour.

This is at home, before you leave for work? Your best bet is backing up to a network storage device on your wireless network. Sadly, Apple just killed off its Time Capsule products, but any NAS box should work. You could even plug in that drive to your router, if it has USB slots, though you'll need to reformat it to NTFS.

Another alternative is to use Cloud Storage as a backup strategy.

Comment: Not even close in answering the question asked , at best this would be a comment with opinion.

Comment: The question is "what would be a better way?"

Answer (score 0):

There is a small and Free app that lets you have more control of Time machine activity.

This does not let you brut force the Eject but will turn off the process in time for you. Just set it so to stop before you wake up.

ie.. Do not back up from 6AM to 11PM

[TimeMachineEditor](https://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/) is a software for macOS that lets you change the default one-hour backup interval of Time Machine. You can change the interval or create a more sophisticated scheduling (see screenshots below).

[image]